# Css menu unclickable links

Tags: html, css, firefox, internet-explorer-10

I built a little drop down menu without using any javascript, but it's not quite co-operating in firefox and IE 10. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Both `Link1` and `Link2` are links. In chrome, clicking on them works fine - I get redirected as expected. In firefox and IE10, however, the menu just closes without visiting the link.

I thought it might be a `z-index` problem but I tried adding that and it didn't seem to do anything. Hovering over those links in firefox does bring up the tooltip showing the link address as well.

Any idea what might be causing this? Or is there a better way to do this? I'd like to try t avoid using javascript if possible.

Markup:

```
<ul class="header-right">
<li>
    <ul class="user-menu">
        <li class="menu-item" tabindex=0 id="submenu_li">
            <span class="sub-menu-header" title="Menu">Long menu name Menu</span>
            <div class="dropdown"></div>
            <div class="user-sub-menu" id="user-sub-menu">
                <ul class="submenu-list">
                    <li class="submenu-item">
                        <a id="a1" href="/Test">Link1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu-item">
                        <a href="/Test2">Link2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Css is kind of long:

```
ul.header-right
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.header-right li
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 2px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

li.menu-item
{
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 10px !important;
}

li.menu-item:hover
{
    background-color: #888888;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li.menu-item:focus #user-sub-menu
{
    display: block;
}

ul.user-sub-menu a, ul.user-sub-menu a:visited
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #232323;
}

div.user-sub-menu
{
    display: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    min-width: 125px;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 22px;
    z-index: 1000;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #232323;
    font-size: 1em;
}

div.user-sub-menu ul
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.user-sub-menu li
{
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

div.user-sub-menu li a, div.user-sub-menu li a:visited
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #232323;
}

div.user-sub-menu li:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #CCFFCC;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mansfield/3sDsj/11/)

Comment: Is there a reason for avoiding JS?

Comment: @DavidStarkey Only my desire to make a menu without it (which I think should be possible). But if I have to use JS, I will :)

Comment: This HTML pattern is superfluous. There is no real need or purpose for the DIVs and SPANs. You should be styling the A-tags, not the list itself, except for positioning.

Comment: @Diodeus Yes, I feared it might be. I think I had some reason for the spans at least...

Comment: You need a simpler pattern. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Diodeus/jejNy/

Comment: @Diodeus I'm trying to avoid using javascript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured out what was happening (or at least, I think I did).

When I focus `li.menu-item` the `#user-sub-menu` div appears as is all well and good. However, if I click on an element inside that div, such as one of the links, technically the `li.menu-item` element has lost the focus and makes the div invisible.

My best guess is that chrome processed the link click before it processed the focus change, and thus things worked right away. For firefox, I added the following css to keep the `#user-sub-menu` div open even when `li.menu-item` loses focus.

```
#user-sub-menu:active, #user-sub-menu:hover, #user-sub-menu:focus
{ 
    display: block;
}
```

As a result this now works fine in Firefox. Unfortunately it still doesn't work in IE, so if anyone else has any insights there I'm happy to hear them, but I'll mark this as answered for now.

Comment: Still a gotcha in 2019 - this exact behavior just showed for me in Chromium 74 (but not in Firefox or Chrome).